# How do i add a value to a char close to cursor position using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to add a value selected from the dropdown to the character close to the cursor position.

What i am trying to do?

when i type @char the dropdown menu opens and when user selects the value from the dropdown it should add that value to whatever is in the input field.

consider i type in "i am @" in the input field
dropdown menu opens up with some values say username1, someuser, nousername

when i select say "someuser" then this input field string should be "i am someuser"

So the below code works if the @ is the last character in the string meaning if user types i am @ and no string after @ it adds the selected value to the last @character

But doesnt work for this. 
say i typein  i am @yahoo and then go to the begining of the input field and enter hey @ so the complete string in input field is like below

"hey @ i am @yahoo" and the cursor is at the first @ char in the string. now when i select value from dropdown menu this selected value gets added to the last @character in the string meaning the output is like below

"hey @ i am someuser"

But the expected ouput is "hey someuser i am @yahoo"

Below is the code,

```
class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
    replace_input_val = (value_in_input, selected_value) => {
        const user_name = selected_value;
        let input_val_without_@;
        input_val_without_@ = value_in_input.slice(0,  
        value_in_input.lastIndexOf('@'));
        if (input_val_without_@ > 0) {
            return input_val_without_@ + selected_value;
        } else {
            return selected_value;
        }
     }


     handle_select_value = (selected_value) => {
         const text = 
             this.replace_input_val(this.state.value_in_input, 
             selected_value);
         this.setState({
             value_in_input: text,
         });
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <input
                onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                value={this.state.value_in_input}/>
            <DropdownMenu 
                onChange={this.handle_select_value}/>
        )
    }
 }
```

I want to add the selected value from dropdownmenu to the @char where the cursor position is at. How can i do it. could someone help me with this thanks.

Comment: you can set data `value` attribute i.e. `<input
                onChange={this.handle_input_change} value={{this.state.value_in_input}}/>`

Comment: thanks. but i want to replace that string after @ with value selected in dropdown and at right position. this function handle-select_value doesnt work as expected so i need some change to it

Comment: If you don't allow to use just @ sign in text maybe you should try to use simple replace on @ sign? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp